# How to make a global module that the variables don't lose its value?

Tags: javascript, import, module, export

I have this in Global.js:

```
let prdcd = [];
let prdds = [];

export const getPrdcd = () => prdcd;
export const setPrdcd = (val) => (prdcd = val);

export const getPrdds = () => prdds;
export const setPrdds = (val) => (prdds = val);
```

The idea is to have this two variables accessible from anywhere in the project.

So in another script I code where prdcd and prdds are both arrays:

```
import * as global from "./Classes/Global.js";
global.setPrdcd(prdcd);
global.setPrdds(prdds);
```

Where prdcd and prdds have content inside and are arrays. I want the values that I am setting in this module to be available and the same in the next module where I do this:

```
import * as global from "./Classes/Global.js";
console.log(global.getPrdds());
console.log(global.getPrdcd());
```

In the console it return an empty array whereas it should have returned some content inside the array. How can I make this work?

Comment: Can you confirm if `prdcd` in `global.setPrdcd(prdcd);` is an array or not?

Comment: Yes they are arrays

Comment: Seems to work here - https://codesandbox.io/s/workspace-js-9vubg?file=/REAMDE.md. Can you check once?